# Sourcery.app artifact instead of Runner.app created during iOS build

Tags: flutter, objectbox, codemagic, flutter-objectbox, sourcery

I am using ObjectBox for Dart/Flutter. As per documentation, iOS requires objectbox_flutter_libs package. However, Adding objectbox_flutter_libs (or objectbox_sync_flutter_libs) to pubspec.yaml causes my Codemagic iOS build to produce "Sourcery.app" artifact instead of the expected Runner.app, affecting my debug process (I am unable to build from Sourcery.app). I see that during the iOS build ObjectBox 1.9.0 is installed, creating the "sourcery.app" directory. I could not find any other reference to Sourcery. I did not see how the target is changed as "Runner.app" settings remain the same in the build logs.

What is the cause of this? Any workaround to get Runner.app instead?

### Basic info:

ObjectBox version: ^2.3.1

Flutter/Dart SDK: Flutter 3.13.7 • Dart 3.1.3

Reproducible: always, as long as "objectbox_flutter_libs" or "objectbox_sync_flutter_libs" added to dependencies
Build OS: macOS M1 Standard VM

Deployment device or OS: n/a (cannot install)

Steps to reproduce:
add objectbox to pubspec, add objectbox_flutter_libs/objectbox_sync_flutter_libs to pubspec, run the generator, pub get, start build

Renaming the folders/updating the previous Runner.app builds' folder content into Sourcery.app folder did not help, nor did the vice versa method, both failed the installation on the device.

### Expected behavior

iOS build produces Runner.app as usual

### Codemagic workflow:

Default WF

Build for:
iOS

Machine:
Mac mini M1

Build triggers:
disabled

Env variables:
none

Dep caching:
disabled

Post-clone script:
none

Pre-test script:
none

Tests:
none

Post-test script:
none

Pre-build script:
none

Flutter channel:
stable

Mode:
profile, no flavors

Xcode version:
latest(15)

CocoaPods version:
default

Project path:
.

Android build format:
AAB

Post-build script:
none

Pre-publish script:
none

Distro:
all disabled

Comment: Sounds like a Codemagic setup issue? This sourcery.app should be ObjectBox's code generator, which is meant be used during build time (only). Maybe that helps...

Comment: can you add Workflow Editor settings or your `codemagic.yaml` file?

Comment: @MikhailTokarev updated, thanks.